# Searching string in file handling

Tags: c++

I am searching student record like student_id, class ,section ,gender, email and telephone number. But this code could not open a file and perform searching.

**code**

```
void searching()
{

    cout << "\t\t\t\tSearching the Record" << endl;

    int offset;
    std::string se_id, se_name, se_email, se_home, se_clas, se_tele, se_cell, se_sec, se_gender, line;
    ifstream filee;
    filee.open("Student.txt");
    cout << "\nType id of student you want to search:";
    cin >> se_id;
    if (filee.is_open())
    {

        while (!filee.eof())
        {
            getline(filee, line);
            if (((offset = line.find(se_id, 0))) != string::npos)
            {
                cout << "\nId ::" << se_id;
                cout << "\nSearch found";
                break;
            }
        }
        filee.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "search not found";
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no question here. Does this not work in some way? Please provide the error message, or your expected output vs actual output.

Comment: What is the structure of the file? And what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Don't do `while (!filee.eof())`, it's almost always wrong. Instead do `while (getline(...))`.

Comment: How is your input file formatted?

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: It can only give the id number . and then i get the record of that student , but it can only give id of student  not the whole record of student.,,,

Comment: @Jamshed Salik Can you give an example of what the input file looks like?

Comment: Id:1
Name:jamshed
Class:3
Section:red
Gender:male
Telephone Number:0312370505
Email:jamshedsalik@yahoo.com
Home Addressrawalpindi

Comment: if id  found in file than it will show the whole student record

Comment: @Jamshed Salik See code below. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you want (see below). I leave it to you to check to make sure the file was opened correctly. Also, it may be helpful to let the user know if there were no records found.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream in("Student.txt");

    int target_id, id;
    cin >> target_id;

    string record, field;
    // while there are records in the file
    while(getline(in, record)) {
        istringstream ss(record);
        ss >> id;
        // Check to see if target id equals record id
        if(target_id == id) {
            cout << id;
            // It does, so let's print the rest of the fields
            while(getline(ss, field, ',')) {
                cout << field << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    in.close();

    return 0;
}
```